# asset.getUrl() outputs double slashes

Tags: templating, assets, content

Craft hasn't done this prior (or maybe I just noticed), but I'm currently battling double slashes in URLs returned from `{{ asset.getUrl() }}`.

The issue appears when I create an Assets field and set the following settings to that field:

*Restrict uploads to a single folder (true)*
*Upload location: [source:Images] `somefolder/somesubfolder`*

Calling `{{ asset.getUrl() }}` on an asset from this field returns the following URL:

**`/uploads/images/somefolder//somesubfolder/image.jpg`**

Notice that the double slash appears inside the path specified in the field's settings – `/uploads/images/` is the source path.

This happens both for Asset fields that are inside Matrix fields, and standalone fields. It also happens regardless if I use named transforms, inline transforms or no transforms (`getUrl(false)`).

*If the source configuration should prove relevant somehow, here's the setup:*

I've got an asset source (local folder) called `Images` configured like this:

*File System Path:* `{imagePath}/`
*URL:* `{imageUri}/`

`{imagePath}` and `{imageUri}` are environment variables, set to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/images"` and `"/uploads/images"`, respectively.

Not sure if this is a bug or something I do wrong somehow (or maybe it has to do with server configurations?). I can remove the double slashes with Twig, but it's annoying. Why does this happen, and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I just setup a test locally exactly as you described and I'm not getting a double `//` path separator. `/Users/Brad/Dropbox/Sites/craft.dev/public/uploads/somefolder/somesubfolder/PT7-2.jpg`

Comment: @BradBell Thanks – it's a weird one. Probably something in my setup somehow. I'll do some debugging and will report back if I find the cause.

Comment: We are getting the same problem in Craft 2.4.2693. It's causing issues with Facebook Open Graph.

Comment: In our case, it was caused by a bad environment in general.php

Comment: @Ryan – I never actually solved this. Can you elaborate? What do you mean by "bad environment"?

Comment: There is an `environmentVariables` array in `general.php`. We were actually generating double-slashes unintentionally. Something like "'assetsImagesUrl'  => SITE_URL.'/uploads/images'", where SITE_URL already had a slash on the end. I only commented to save others from the same mistake - I don't think it's your issue.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't my issue, but it's definitely something that can easily happen. Thanks for clearing it up @Ryan!